# React App suddenly stopped working without me changing anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, metamask, babel-loader

Hey guys so I forked a react app(https://github.com/conedex/frontend) which worked perfectly but suddenly it stopped working with the following error:

`./node_modules/@metamask/utils/node_modules/superstruct/dist/index.mjs 46:43 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (46:43) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. var path = failure.path; var msg = path.length === 0 ? message : "At path: >".concat(path.join('.'), " -- ").concat(message); _this = _super.call(this, explanation ?? msg);   if (explanation != null) _this.cause = msg; Object.assign(_assertThisInitialized(_this), rest);`

Ive tried a lot of things on here but nothing really worked, after deleting node_modules and reinstalling it again for the about 20th time it suddenly worked once, after stopping and starting the react server with yarn again it stopped working again with the same error.

Can someone please help me? This error makes me insane.

I tried

`yarn start`

and I expected it to work

Comment: tried to remove `package-lock.json`? please make a backup before doing so, or rename it to something else. though, make sure whatever antivirus you had not suddenly going autistic and removing stuff in `node_modules`.

Comment: @BagusTesa _"autistic"_ not a great turn of phrase to use here.

Comment: @Andy my bad, i am sorry for the offense. anyway, if you could guide our good friend jay here that would be cool. personally i can't discount the possibility that some external forces at play causing the problem at hand.

Comment: Looking at the commits for that repo there have been some changes made over the last week up to yesterday. OP have you tried cloning it again? @BagusTesa no harm done but many people who work with code are on the spectrum, and its just a poor choice of word. Thanks for acknowledging it.

Comment: @Andy yeah I have checked the releases but they don't impact package-lock.json. Using older versions hasn't helped either sadly

Comment: If you look at the error @JayCole it doesn't appear to be to do with this repo (as such). It's pointing to `superstruct`, and there is a [similar issue](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/superstruct/issues/1157) (from 2022). But `superstruct` is also a dependency of `metamask` so it might be to do with how _that's_ handling something. It's difficult to tell. If all else fails get in contact with the dev of this repo and point out the problem.

Comment: @Andy hey thanks for pointing that out, have gotten to him before I made this post and he said he can't help me sadly. I will try just more or give up I guess. I have found someone else who had a similar issue on here and he never got an answer sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today, as I have a custom webpack config.

Add .mjs loader to your webpack config.

Also, if this does not help, make sure that you have nullish-coalescing-operator babel plugin!

```
{
  test: /\.mjs$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@metamask)\/).*/,
  use: 'babel-loader',
},
```

You can add some other package to this config

```
{
  test: /\.mjs$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@metamask|some-other-package)\/).*/,
  use: 'babel-loader',
},
```